# Download de arquivo com mvc está dando pau

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Fiz várias pesquisas na net para encontrar uma forma de eu gerar uma planilha e salvar no disco.

Como se trata de web, isso só pode ser feito via download, e todos os exemplos pesquisados(pelo menos por mim), eu caio no **FileResult**. Acontece que não está funcionando.

Peguei um exemplo simples e dá o mesmo erro. Veja o código

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Nessa linha eu obtenho o erro

```
return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

Esse é o erro:

> Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method.

Como eu resolvo esse erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no facto de, quase de certeza, estar a utilizar a classe `System.IO.File`, que é estática, logo não pode ser instanciada ou retornada.

Experimente alterar a linha

`return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);`

Para:

`return System.Web.Mvc.File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);`

Comment: Diz que **File does not exists in the NameSpace System.Web.Mvc** e se troco para FileResult dá o erro do post original

Comment: Estranho, segundo a documentação da Microsoft isso existe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File%28System.String,System.String,System.String%29

Comment: Lendo a documentação agora é que entendi que não poderia usar fora de uma controller. Já corrigido.